# Ember sort data from another controller from an ember-data model association

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I have a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/watab/6/

Which is a simplified version of my end goal. Basically I need sort data that is in the hasMany association.

If a User hasMany Books and I want to sort the books for displaying with `{{#each book in books}}` then how do I sort them?

What I am doing is in the user route during `setupController` I set the content for the books controller.

```
this.controllerFor('books').set('content', model.get('books'));
```

And now in the Users controller I set the needs of course

```
needs: ['books']
```

And set an alias

```
books: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.books.content')
```

Now I have books controller

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  sortAscending: false
});
```

However when I do my `{{#each book in books}}` it is never sorted.

The jsbin http://jsbin.com/watab/6/ isn't exactly what I described but it employs the basic ideas I have described here.

This is the same jsbin http://jsbin.com/watab/7/ except I changed the `sortAscending` to `true`. And I get the same results...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the thing, taking the example of the JSBin here http://jsbin.com/watab/6/, when you're in the 'index' template, your current controller is 'IndexController', that's fine. In that controller you have a property 'users', that's fine; however, that property's content is not sorted, even if you defined the sorting options in the UsersController, that property won't be sorted, why ?, controllers are decorators for your models, so, that code you put for sorting will work whenever you go to the 'users' route, then, the users will be sorted there, that's why it doesn't work in your 'IndexController', because the data is not sorted. To sort it, there are a few ways, but I like this one, in your 'IndexController', add these properties:

```
userSortProperties: ['name:desc'],
sortedUsers: Ember.computed.sort('users', 'userSortProperties')
```

and change your template to this:

```
{{#each user in sortedUsers}}
  <div>{{user.name}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Beauty! That works indeed! http://jsbin.com/watab/8/edit and http://jsbin.com/watab/9/edit